# How to sync GreaseMonkey scripts between computers?

Tags: firefox, script, sync, firefox-extensions, greasemonkey

I have some great greasemonkey scripts for FireFox and would ideally have a way to sync them between computers.  To some degree, it would even be nice to be able to deploy the scripts to PC's across a network at the office.

How can I sync these between workstations?

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to synchronize Greasemonkey scripts (and all related data) using a Google Chrome extension. I'll try to find an extension that can do this.

Comment: Today, I found out that it's possible to synchronize Greasemonkey scripts in Google Chrome using Tampermonkey: http://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=414

Comment: Please check the [updated answer](http://superuser.com/a/743630/301042) and see if you can accept it or not.

Comment: Please change the accepted answer or modify the question to be specific to historic Firefox. The currently accepted answer hasn't worked for 7 years

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I use [Dropbox](https://www.getdropbox.com/referrals/NTIyMjkzOQ) to sync greasemonkey scripts:

1. Make a folder: `My Dropbox\App Sync\Firefox\`
2. Find your profile directory (`[random string]` wil be something like `2b5dk3bs`)

   - XP: `C:\Documents and Settings\[username]\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[random string].default`
   - Vista: `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[random string].default`
3. Move the `gm_scripts` folder to `My Dropbox\App Sync\Firefox\`
4. Use the [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) to create a Junction called `gm_scripts` in the profile directory. A Junction is kind of like a symbolic link. To do this, right-click the `gm_scripts` folder in your Dropbox and click 'Pick Link Source'. Then, in your profile directory, right-click and pick Drop As >> Junction.
5. For every other machine, delete the `gm_scripts` folder in your profile, and add the junction as before.

I also use this trick for extensions, [mouse gestures redox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/39) config, [stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108), and [menu editor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/710) files.

Comment: Sweet idea. I've been wanting to do the same thing but never found a way to do it.

Comment: In Windows 7 you can use "mklink -J" to create junction.

Comment: Where would the scripts be stored on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 7):

Since Greasemonkey's December 2013 [1.13 release](http://www.greasespot.net/2013/12/greasemonkey-113-release.html) there is an option to use Firefox Sync to keep installed User Scripts the same on all your browsers.

See also a September 2013 blog post: [Firefox Sync coming to Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/2013/09/firefox-sync-coming-to-greasemonkey.html).

Comment: This is the latest updated answer. It was written in 2014, since other answers were in 2009.

Comment: This option only syncs scripts which are installed and updated from a web link. It's pretty useless if you are the author of some unpublished scripts which you want to sync between multiple machines.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Firefox [Environment Backup Extension](http://softwarebychuck.com/febe/febe.html) (FEBE) to make backups of ALL Firefox related stuff, including extensions as Greasemonkey

Answer (score 0):

I just finished setting up [Windows Live Mesh](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh) to sync my greasemonkey scripts.  This works on Vista SP2 or higher, or Mac OS X 10.5 or newer.  Those who want maximum availability to XP and linux should still look at tghw's answer.  However, for those who only need to sync to more recent versions of Windwos and OS X, Windows Live Mesh is a good option that does not require creating junctions.

1. Install Windows Live Mesh on each
   machine & sign up.
2. Find gm_scripts directory (C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles[random
       string].default\gm_scripts)
3. Select "Sync a folder" in Windows Live Mesh and paste in your
       gm_scripts path.
4. You can choose to which machines to
   sync to, and you can also sync to
       SkyDrive.
5. Windows Live Mesh will start
   syncing.